# Verb for "I wish I were" him?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a verb to describe a person who you wish you could be?  For example, if you wish you were Bob, then

> I **__** Bob.

Comment: then you *wish you were Bob*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Envy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envy)* (as a verb) may not necessarily imply a wish to lose or subsume one’s own identity in favor of another’s, but I think it is as close a word as you will find.

Answer (score 1):

For a more positive connotation, "idolize". It also doesn't have the subsumption desire inherently implied. "emulate" would be an active form where you're actively trying to change yourself to be more like Bob.